# Creating table in Athena through code results in error : mismatched input 'ROW' expecting {<EOF>, 'WITH'}

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a table in athena through code.
[Here is the query I use to create the table](https://gist.github.com/ankita-kumari/5ea92cd7e7ae62c1841c5ab44b9c1cdb)

I am getting this error :

```
com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.InvalidRequestException: line 119:1: mismatched input 'ROW' expecting {<EOF>, 'WITH'} (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 6c48eb7a-ab4b-4c60-b4e1-85c3bb3ace05)
```

Similar query works just fine via the athena console.

I tried all of the things mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42811075/4179190) answer and those didn't work either.

What is causing the issue?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: I got this error when I was missing the closing quote on my LOCATION string. I had written `...LOCATION 's3://.../prefix;` with no closing single quote. The error messages that Athena produces are not at all helpful.